# Android - HTML5 - SQLite

Tags: android, html, sqlite

I wanted to build an application that runs on android using purely html, javascript and a database ( sqlite maybe? ). I have not done android development before. My question is that is it possible to develop a database application for android using only html, javascript and a database? Is there any other better database supported than sqlite?

Thanking you
Imran

Comment: @Lucifer - As I have mentioned I am totally new to android development and would not know what to try and therefor the question. I have done a hello world using the sdk but html, javascript development is much faster so I wanted to switch to that. I tried searching the net and found some a project called PhoneGap which might work but I am not sure about the longevity of that project.Googling for 'html5 android sqlite' did not get me many relevant results. Now stop being a jerk.

Comment: @Imran, did one of the answers work for you?

Comment: @Andreas Ka I have not got a chance to try it yet but I went through the link on the official android website you posted and it seems it should work. Thanks again, as soon as I try it I will mark your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 possible approaches:

1. Use a webview to embed your html5 application and add a Javascript interface with a database access layer:
   http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html
2. Use the Phonegap framework to access the SQLite database from Javascript:
   http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.7.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android

Answer (score 1):

What you want can not be achieved directly on Android: HTML & JavaScript do not have an interface for accessing SQLite databases.

The only way this can be done is using a App framework like PhoneGap that generates an App from your HTML & JavaScript code.